# How should I pass this on to my component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using server-side rendering on my page.tsx and I have created a component named `AdToCart` for my button:

AdToCart component:

```
"use client";

import React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

const AddToCart = (props) => {
  const test = props;
  return (
    <Button
      onClick={() => {
        alert({ test });
      }}
      variant="contained"
      sx={{ width: "100%" }}
    >
      View Product
    </Button>
  );
};

export default AddToCart;
```

And I have put it in page.tsx like this:

```
export default async function ProductCard() {
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={1} justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
      {Myjson.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.ID}>
          <Grid>
            <Card>
              <AddToCart url={item.url} />
            </Card>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      ))}
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

So whenever I click on the button, I see `[object Object]`

I see an error saying:

> Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.

And then I use `props:string` and I see on the page.tsx this error:

> Type '{ url: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

`item.url` is a string, and I just want to make the button component access it or at least open that url.

How should I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues:

1. **TypeScript Error with Props**: The error "Parameter **'props'** implicitly has an 'any' type" is because TypeScript expects you to define the type of the props in your `AddToCart` component. You can fix this by defining an interface for the props.
2. **Passing and Using Props**: You're trying to pass `url` as a prop to `AddToCart`, but within `AddToCart`, you're not using it correctly. Instead of trying to alert an object, you should directly use the `url` prop.
3. **Opening the URL**: If you want the button to navigate to the URL, you need to use `window.location.href` or a similar method to navigate.

Let's refactor the code:

**AddToCart Component** -

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

// Define an interface for your props
interface AddToCartProps {
  url: string;
}

const AddToCart: React.FC<AddToCartProps> = ({ url }) => {
  return (
    <Button
      onClick={() => {
        window.location.href = url; // Use the url to navigate
      }}
      variant="contained"
      sx={{ width: "100%" }}
    >
      View Product
    </Button>
  );
};

export default AddToCart;
```

**ProductCard Component** -

```
import React from "react";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import AddToCart from "./AddToCart"; // Adjust the import path as needed

// Assuming Myjson is defined somewhere in your code
const Myjson = [{ ID: "1", url: "http://example.com" }, /* ... other items ... */];

const ProductCard: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={1} justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
      {Myjson.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.ID}>
          <Grid item>
            <Card>
              <AddToCart url={item.url} />
            </Card>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      ))}
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default ProductCard;
```

Comment: Are you recommending converting my `page.tsx` into a component? I only needed to correct the AddToCart component. Why should I make `page.tsx` a component?

Answer (score 0):

The prop `url` was passed correctly.

The type of AddToCart props is `{url: string}` and the value of test variable is like this.

```
{ url: 'https://some.url' }
```

If you log `{ test }` in console, it will be like this.

```
{
  test: {
     url: "https://some.url"
  }
}
```

But the object variable can't be displayed in alert. If you want to see it in alert, you can use JSON.strigify.

```
alert(JSON.strigify({ test }));
```